# How to validate a specific json value for a key in localstorage object in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am unable to assert a specific value in json returned by cookie dropped in localstorage object
Here is the json code which is the value of the key

```
categories: {6: true}
consent_date: "2022-05-12T11:44:37.906Z"
consent_type: 1
cookies: {1: true}
```

I want to assert categories has value 6 and true
I am able to get hold of key but unable to get hold of values
Below is my cypress code

```
 cy.get('#_evidon-accept-button').wait(5000).click().then(()=>
    {
       localStorage.getItem('_evidon_consent_ls_32029')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [chai's `expect`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) to assert on the value.

```
cy.get('#_evidon-accept-button')
  .wait(5000)
  .click()
  .then(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('_evidon_consent_ls_32029')
    expect(data.categories).to.equal({6: true});     
  })
```

Comment: Getting expected undefined to equal { '6': true }

Comment: Is the localStorage item set? Does it have a property of `categories`?

Comment: Do I need to manually set in cypress before firing chai assertion?

Comment: You shouldn't need to if your application is setting the localStorage.

Comment: I m still not able to get the issue solved.please help me

Comment: Is your application setting the localStorage item?

Comment: It drops a cookie with key and value in localstorage object

Comment: Is the localStorage item set at the point that you click on the button, or later? It might be a race condition, where Cypress is checking for the localStorage item before it is actually set.